# ASP.Net TableHeaderRow controller produces tr not th

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

This is my code

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="table" CssClass="table">
            <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                <asp:TableCell>Date</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>TotalInboundCalls</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>GhostCalls</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>AnserdCalls</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>AVGDurationTime</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>AVGTakingTime</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>AVGWaitingTime</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>AvgRingingTime</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>AvgHoldTime</asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>
        </asp:Table>
```

The generated html is `tr` not `th`, What wrong did I do please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well TR is correct, your TableCell will produce a TD, to get a TH you need to use 
`<asp:TableHeaderCell>` instead